# Using `chroot`: Why do I get error from running `sudo chroot /bin /bash`?

Tags: linux, shell, command

> Using `chroot`: Why do I get error from running `sudo chroot /bin /bash` ?

I understand from documentation that `chroot` should execute `/bin/bash` and that `/bin` is the new root directory for this command.

Why do I get an error ?

Here is the terminal output:

```
nlykkei@nlykkei-ThinkPad-X200s ~ $ sudo chroot /bin /bash
[sudo] password for nlykkei: 
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bash’: No such file or directory
```

I am running Linux Mint 17 64-bit.

Comment: Saying cant find dir or file.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. It is indeed weird!

Comment: I've updated with output from command, I can also provide a screenshot.

Comment: It is indeed weird if the exact same command works on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant `sudo chroot /bin/bash` without the space. If you have the space in, linux will interpret your command as 1 program with 2 arguments, while the chroot command is only expecting 1 argument.

Comment: Writing --help shows chroot takes an CMD argument optional ?